# How to send an email from within my app using the SMS style interface?

Tags: objective-c, ios, email

I have created an iPhone SMS style interface and was wondering if I could send an email in the app to a certain person and if that certain person replies, it would appear as a new line (just as if you were getting a new SMS)... How can I do this without using Apple's mail client (because this pulls up a new view controller, but I want it to mail in the background)? What's the best way of doing this? I can have POP3 and login details taken from UITextFields.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [MessageUI Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html). Check [MFMailComposeViewController Class Reference docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008200) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can send email without the apple mail client with [this](https://github.com/kailoa/iphone-smtp), maybe you can modify it for checking an email arrival!

Hope this helps!

Comment: don't think I can modify it to do that unfortunately :(